# VHDL - Phase Accumulator with feedback

Tags: vhdl, feedback, accumulator, phase

I am trying to create a phase accumulator using VHDL that has the following characteristics.

Inputs:

- D (Input signal)
- RESET
- CE
- CLK

Outputs:

- Q (output signal - feedback)

Source code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity Phase_accu is
port (
    D       : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    CE      : in std_logic;
    CLK     : in std_logic;
    RESET   : in std_logic;
    Q       : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
);
end Phase_accu;

architecture Behavioral of Phase_accu is
begin

process(D, CE, CLK, RESET)
    begin
        if RESET = '1' then
            Q <= "0000000000000000";
        elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
            if CE = '1' then
                Q <= ("000000000000" & D) + Q;
            end if;
        end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I get an error with the line trying to merge together the 2 signals for feedback...

```
Q <= ("000000000000" & D) + Q;
```

Cannot read output "Q".

Comment: Removing the superfluous `use` before `library` on the first line of your code and using VHDL revision -2008 your code analyzes and elaborates (evaluating a port of mode out is possible in -2008). Please provide a [mcve] including complete error message and identifying the operation your tool was performing, the problem isn't guaranteed reproducible from your question as is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't read the value of an `out` in VHDL revisions prior to VHDL-2008. The usual way to get around this is to have an internal copy of your output, and use that internal copy when you need to get its value:

```
[...]
Q : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
[...]
signal Q_reg : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

process(D, CE, CLK, RES)
    begin

        if RES = '1' then
            Q_reg <= "0000000000000000";
        elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
            if CE = '1' then
                Q_reg <= ("000000000000" & D) + Q_reg;
            end if;
        end if;
end process;

Q <= Q_reg;
```

Comment: I understand now. Thankyou very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use numeric_std library instead of STD_LOGIC_ARITH and STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED. I also suggest to make some minor optimizations regarding the vector size specification.

Also the sensitivity list has two many entries. You have to remove D and CE to describe a valid clocked process with asynchronous reset. See your Synthesis tool manual for details.

This makes the code above to

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Phase_accu is
port (
    D       : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    CE      : in std_logic;
    CLK     : in std_logic;
    RESET   : in std_logic;
    Q       : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
);
end Phase_accu;

architecture Behavioral of Phase_accu is
    signal Q_reg : unsigned(Q'range);
begin

process(CLK, RES)
begin

        if RES = '1' then
            Q_reg <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
            if CE = '1' then
                Q_reg <= resize(unsigned(D), Q_reg'length) + Q_reg;
            end if;
        end if;

end process;

Q <= std_logic_vector(Q_reg);

end Behavioral;
```